# R create matrix or data frame from string with braces ('{' '}')

Tags: r

I have some data in the following format: "{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}". I would like to create a data frame or a matrix from this data. E.g. using each internal '{ }' delimited group as a row or a column.

I've tested usual data.frame and matrix without sucess: (e.g. `matrix("{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}")` or `data.frame("{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}")`)

Is it possible or I need to convert this to another format?

Comment: You may need `jsonlite` package

Comment: For simple cases you might be able to handle the input with regular expressions, e.g. `read.table(text = gsub("[{}]", "", gsub("(?<=\\})\\s*,\\s*(?=\\{)", "\n", "{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}", perl = TRUE)), header = FALSE, sep = ",")`, but this will be inefficient for even moderately large inputs. You would be much better off addressing *why* that format is being used in the first place and working from there.

Comment: @nrussell: thank you. Actually, this format comes from a 3rd party program and I can't change it.

Comment: @akrun: thanks, `jsonlite` works like a charm in this case, e.g.  `fromJSON(chartr( "{}", "[]", "{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonlite` offers a possible solution for this problem (thanks @akrun).
E.g. `fromJSON(chartr( "{}", "[]", "{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}"))`